# how to add a number to a column record and put the results in another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, case

I have a view with 4 columns. I want to be able to add a number to the rank(column) records and put the new rank in a new column, sorted in ascending order.

```
USE database;
GO

SELECT [ID]
      ,[rank]
      ,[CONTRACTOR]
      ,[Trades]
       CASE 
         WHEN rank < 5 THEN rank + 1
         ELSE 1
      END

FROM [database].[schema].[table]
ORDER BY rank ;

GO
```

I am getting error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: It seems that you've left comma "," before CASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a comma before `CASE`

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[rank]
      ,[CONTRACTOR]
      ,[Trades]
      ,CASE 
         WHEN rank < 5 THEN rank + 1
         ELSE 1
      END

FROM [database].[schema].[table]
ORDER BY rank ;
```

Comment: Thanks. How I put the results in a column I created, "New Rank" and sort the results by rank in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

At least you are missing a comma before `CASE`.

Comment: Thanks. How I put the results in a column I created, "New Rank" and sort the results by rank in ascending order?

Comment: I would suggest removing your original question because like it is now, it is of no help for the community.